# SetDllDirectory by thread

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, dll

To use in different threads a non-reentrant DLL, I'm copying it in 4 different folders. It's ugly but mandatory...
This DLL is manually loaded by my application and uses another sublib (which is implicitly linked to the other). So I have something like this :

```
folder1/
   lib1.dll
   sublib.dll
folder2/
   lib2.dll
   sublib.dll
```

I managed to load the different versions of lib.dll (lib1 and lib2) but the loaded sublib.dll remains the same for both.
I tried the SetDllDirectory and, AddDllDirectory but it's not loading multiple sublib.dll.

```
 for (size_t i { 1 }; i <= threadsCount; ++i)
 {
        SetDllDirectoryA(nullptr); // Reset.
        //SetDllDirectoryA(""); // Plug "binary planting" security hole. `
        SetDllDirectoryA(dirPath(i).c_str());   // folderX

        HMODULE module = LoadLibraryExA(libPath(i).c_str(), nullptr, LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_USER_DIRS);
        if (!module )
        {
            std::cout << "error loading dll" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }

        // Used after
        // FooPrototype foo = (FooPrototype) GetProcAddress(module, "foo");
}

// Run threads with the different 'foo'
```

Is it possible to load 2 instances of sublib.dll ??

Thanks !

Comment: Is it possible to relink lib1 so that it refers to sublib1.dll?

Comment: I think your problem may be that Windows sees you are trying to load `sublib.dll` and says "ah-ha!", I've already got a copy of that in memory - I'll just use that."

Comment: Can you make sublib.dll be a delay-load dll?  You can do all *sorts* of interesting tricks with those.

Comment: @MartinBonner Thanks,but what is a delay-load dll ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-support-for-delay-loaded-dlls?view=vs-2017

Comment: I'm using Qt. I put this in the .pro file of lib.dll :
QMAKE_LFLAGS_DEBUG += /DELAYLOAD:sublib.dll

But I got this :
unresolved external symbol __delayLoadHelper2

while I linked sublib.lib in the lib.dll project.

Comment: Yup.  You need to write that function.  That's where you get to do all the exciting stuff.  (But if you can link lib.dll, you can link it four times, and make it link against a different copy of sublib.dll each time).

Comment: I think I have then to loadLibrary(sublib) and with that I still have common values.